# How to import Cloudflare KV Namespace Variable?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-apps, wrangler, cloudflare-kv

I'm using KV namespace defined in `cargo.toml` by adding to it the lines

```
kv_namespaces = [
  { binding = "SITE_DATA", id = "<test-site-id>" }
]
```

When I try to import the `SITE_DATA` variable in my Worker script as shown, and I run `wrangler publish` or `wrangler build`, I get the error

```
[tsl] ERROR in /home/x/test/src/handlers/foo.ts(1,29)
      TS2306: File '/home/x/test/node_modules/@cloudflare/workers-types/index.d.ts' is not a module.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
```

Why is this error happening, and how do we properly import `SITE_DATA` so that we can do things like `SITE_DATA.put("data", data)`?

**src/handlers/foo.ts**

```js
import { KVNamespace } from '@cloudflare/workers-types'

declare const SITE_DATA: KVNamespace

export const Foo = async () => {
  const data = {
    title: 'Hello World',
  }
  SITE_DATA.put('posts', JSON.stringify(data))

  return new Response("ok")
}
```

Based on https://levelup.gitconnected.com/create-a-api-on-the-edge-using-typescript-and-cloudflare-workers-e71fea7fc1b6

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strict": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": [
      "@cloudflare/workers-types",
      "@types/jest",
      "@types/service-worker-mock"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrangler will look for a `wrangler.toml` unless told otherwise. `cargo.toml` means nothing in this context, given it isn't a rust project.

once you've renamed your config file to `wrangler.toml` (or modified your build script to point to `cargo.toml` in despite of the least astonishement principle) you'll need to declare your globals in an ambient module `src/bindings.d.ts`

```
declare global  {
    const WHATEVER: string;
    const SITE_DATA: KVNamespace;
}
```

You shouldn't explicitly import workers types. Having it on tsconfig will already let your IDE take advantage of the definitions.

When in module format, workers won't put your bindings on the global scope. They will come as properties for the `env` argument. No ambient declaration is due.

```
export default  {
   fetch:(request, env, ctx) {
       // Here, env.SITE_DATA  is a KVNamespace
   }
}
```